# Ghostscript behavior using ps2write

Tags: memory, ghostscript

I have a script that utilizes Ghostscript to convert PDF files to PostScript.  Additionally these files needed to be padded with blank pages because they are printed on both sides of the paper and each documents needs to be kept separate.  The process from a high level goes like this:

1. Convert all PDF files in a directory to individual PostScript files
   and during that process pad each one with a blank page if it has an
   odd number of pages as indicated in the beginning of the PostScript
   header.
2. The list of all these PostScript files is then passed back to
   Ghostscript to create a single PostScript document to be printed.
3. This is a requirement of the process that all the documents are
   submitted as a single print job.

The initial part of the process proceeds without issue, however the second part seems to run into problems after a certain threshold(large number of PDF files) is reached.  The command line I use for the second part is:

```
gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=ps2write -sOutputFile=$print_tmp $list_tmp
```

Where `print_tmp` is the single PostScript file to be printed and `list_tmp` represents the list of individual PostScript files to combine into the one file.

I have seen no issued when printing as many as 750 files, but after about a 1000 I observed the following behavior.  The `gs` process appears to be churning through each file and memory usage slowly increases.  After it's allocated roughly about 675MB of memory the process seems to slow down significantly and in fact never seems to complete.

For 500 files the process took about 45 minutes.  With about 1400 files the process was still going after 5 hours and memory consumption was about 1GB.  The memory utilization for the 500 files was about 600MB.  I imagine at some point the process would finish, but I have a time window that I have to fit into.

Is there something that needs to be tuned for this or have I reached a limitation of the `ps2write` device?  Using the `pswrite` device I can process over 2000 files in 2 hours so it seems that the task is at least possible, but I'd prefer to get away from `pswrite` since its deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to suggest a different process path for you to explore:

1. Skip your step 1 altogether (where you convert your input PDFs into `ps2write`-generated PS files first and add an empty page to those which contain odd page numbers).
2. Process all your input PDF files directly (and add a `-c showpage` PostScript code snippet after each odd-numbered PDF file).

This requires you to retrieve the even/odd page information from the input PDF files through other means (which I'll not deal with here for now -- just saying you could use a `pdfinfo` command in order to gain this info).

This would lead to a command line looking like this:

```
gs \
  -o ps2-output.ps \
  -sDEVICE=ps2write \
  -f even1.pdf \
  -f odd1.pdf -c showpage \
  -f odd2.pdf -c showpage \
  -f even2.pdf \
  -f even3.pdf \
  -f odd3.pdf -c showpage \
  [...]
```

`-c showpage` adds an empty page whenever it appears within the list of input files.

Note, that you are *required* to use the `-f` switch after each use of the `-c` switch (but I'm using it for each input file here anyway).

Of course I don't know for sure if this method would give you any improvement when it comes to number of input files processed by Ghostscript, but it's worth a try...